# Loop through array, add if needed, get count again

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a set of data that I need to loop through, that contains a number of pieces of information, Quantity, decimalLength (in inches), purchaseLength (in feet).

I set up my loops by first pulling the data from MySQL with a Result>If>While loop, then I use a second one to loop through each section of the first result. What I need to do not is loop through the final set of data and check to see if the value for a given row is smaller than or equal to an item in an array, if not, go to the next item in the array and check again, and if it reaches the end, then it needs to add a new item to the array, and use that value.

I have it started, but I am not sure where to go from here... code as follows:

```
<?php

    $servername = "redacted";
    $username   = "redacted";
    $password   = "redacted";
    $dbname     = "redacted";
    $conn       = new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );
    $sql        = "SELECT DISTINCT material FROM temptable WHERE material != 'MISC STEEL'";
    $result     = $conn->query( $sql );
    if ( $result->num_rows > 0 ) {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ) {
            $material = $row[ 'material' ];
            $sql2    = "SELECT cutLengths, material, decimalLength, purchaseLength FROM temptable WHERE material = '$material'";
            $result2 = $conn->query( $sql2 );
            if ( $result2->num_rows > 0 ) {
                echo "<h2>$material</h2><hr/>";
                while ( $row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    $arr = array( );
                    array_push($arr, $row2[ 'decimalLength' ]);
                    for ( $i = 0; $i < $row2[ 'cutLengths' ]; $i++ ) {
                        echo $row2[ 'decimalLength' ] . "<br/>";
                        for ( $j = 0; $j < count( $arr ); $j++ ) {
                            if ( $row2[ 'decimalLength' ] <= $arr[ $j ] ) {
                                $arr[ $j ] = $arr[ $j ] - $row2[ 'decimalLength' ];
                                echo $arr[ $j ] . "<br/>";
                            }
                            elseif ( $row2[ 'decimalLength' ] > $arr[ $j ]  ) {
                                $arr[] = $row2[ 'decimalLength' ];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                echo "<h4>(" . count( $arr ) . ") Total " . $row2[ 'purchaseLength' ] . "' Length(s)</h4>";
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

I know I am on the right track, and I know it can be done, I just don't know what to do next.

EDIT: My current code outputs this:

**Angle Steel 2 x 2 x 1/8**

79.875
0
79.875
0
55.875
0
55.875
0
41.875
0
41.875
0
**(2) Total ' Length(s)**

What it SHOULD be doing is seeing that the value of the 79.875 is larger than the 0, adding a new value to the array, and using it for the math.

Comment: can you provide a small sample of data and what your code is outputting compared to your desired result output.

Comment: Please see my Edit above.

Comment: Let's clean up this old post.  Please clarify your expected output, I'll post something acceptable so that this page can be closed.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not at that job anymore, and I can't remember what it was supposed to do. I can delete this question if that would help.